# Android and iOS testing tools/frameworks

Tags: android, ios, testing, integration-testing

What are the most common testing tools for Android and iOS? Is it advisable to use an platform independent tool? 
What choices do i have when it comes to testing and Jenkins server?
Would be nice if one could make a list of tools and maybe some good tutorials (beginner in programming and testing).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you should look for a platform independent tool depends on a variety of factors, including but not limited to:

- how OS-specific your apps are
- how much you like (or dislike) instrumentation in your code for testing
- the level of testing you intend to automate

[Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso) is one of the better options for Android, since it's directly supported by Google.  The tests are written in Java and can directly reference the UI elements they are attempting to manipulate.

In iOS, automation must pass through Apple's UIAutomation framework, which is only programmable in a modified version of Javascript that Apple created specifically for this purpose (although other frameworks attempt to expose APIs in other languages).  There are many good options here.  We wrote [Illuminator](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator) to be able to run our iOS integration tests on Jenkins CI.  It provides a flexible command line and JUnit reports.

Answer (score 1):

Try EZTestApp: http://www.tenkod.com/ez-testapp/ - I haven't tried it yet, but it looks cool. Also, XCTest is the standard for iOS with JUnit being the standard for Android. BDD or TDD? Be more specific!

Comment: I haven't decided yet if it should be BDD or TDD. Just need a general list of options that i have in each section if its not to much to ask.

Comment: http://justjoey.co.uk/2015/01/the-programmers-toolbelt/ - I've written a post there that has a small list of things I've used. Hope that helps.

Comment: Think TDD would be best for my situation

Comment: I'd recommend XCTest for iOS as it's now much better than it ever has been. With Android, JUnit is the standard, although I've heard good things about Robolectric - http://robolectric.org